# UICollectionViewCells not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, phasset

I'm making an app where you can have a profile pic for your account. Of course, I had to make a photo picker as one option for getting a photo. At first I was going to use UIImagePickerController but then I read about the Swift 3 "Photos" module. I've programmed most of the whole picker screen but I still have a display problem. Instead of laying the photos out nicely, 3 per row, as I coded it to do, the view looks like this when I run the app:

[image: Picker view]

Obviously, this is not what I want the view to look like. Here is my code for the cell generating method.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    var assetThumbnailSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width/3, height: self.view.frame.width/3)

    let asset = assets[indexPath.row]

    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: assetThumbnailSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info)in
        if let image = result {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = image
            cell.addSubview(imageView)
            imageView.bounds = cell.bounds
        }
    })

    return cell
}
```

I also made the cell size the same as the imageView size. Here is the code for that method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width/3, height: self.view.frame.width/3)
}
```

I think the reason it's displaying with huge spaces in between the images is because of how I set it up in the interface builder, which I didn't think would matter because I modified it programmatically:

[image: Interface builder]

So basically I think the interface builder setup is overruling the programmatic setup. If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this problem I would be grateful!

Comment: are you using auto layout  ?

Comment: ok give the collection view 4 edges constrains and try to change the background color of the collection view any color other than white to can know what the problem in cells or in collection view

Comment: Ok so for the edges constraints I can't do that because it's a UICollectionViewController. Doesn't allow me to set constraints. And for changing the background color the result in the app was the same screen but just with the new background that I set

Comment: let cellWidth = (collectionView.frame.width/3) - 10 which is the min spacing between cells set at storyboard or by delegate

Comment: Ok I'll try that

Comment: I'm sure that solution would work, it's just that the interface builder setup I think is overruling my programming setup of the view so it still looks the same